# Migración desde VB6 a VS2017 tiene problemas con MSMAPI

Tags: email, vb6, microsoft

Estoy trabajando en una migración y no puedo resolver este problema.

> Error BC30002
>   No está definido el tipo 'MSMAPI.MAPISession'.
>   Generales D:\NET\Generales\Generales\Util\Funciones\FuncionesMail.vb
>   Error BC30002  No está definido el tipo 'MSMAPI.MAPIMessages'.  Generales D:\NET\Generales\Generales\Util\Funciones\FuncionesMail.vb
>   Error BC30451  'MSMAPI' no está declarado. Puede que sea inaccesible debido a su nivel de protección.
>   Generales D:\NET\Generales\Generales\Util\Funciones\FuncionesMail.vb

Intenté descargandolos mapiheaders y poniendolo en varias carpetas sin éxito.

Código de ejemplo

```
Dim objMensaje As New MSMAPI.MAPIMessages
    With objMensaje
        .SessionID = objSesion.SessionID
        .Compose()
        .MsgSubject = pAsunto
        .MsgNoteText = pMensaje
        .RecipIndex = 0
        .RecipType = MSMAPI.RecipTypeConstants.mapToList
        .RecipAddress = pDestinatario
```

Comment: perdón, no me di cuenta que estaba en el foro en español

Comment: Y que tipo de objeto es eso? agregaste la referencia?

Comment: no te sabría decir que tipo de dato es porque es un pedazo de código de una migración que estoy realizando, al parecer es MAPIMessages el objeto que esta generando.

Comment: Y puede que no exista esa clase de objeto.. no seria mejor reescribir el codigo? que tipo de mensaje y a quien queres mandar?

Comment: Hmm..MSMAPI es un ocx de vb6? Veo improbable que te funcione. Pero si lo que quieres es enviar correos hay librerías nativas en .net

Comment: yo también pienso que vamos a tener que volver a reescribir este bloque de código, pero al ser una migración estoy buscando alternativas a editar el código

Comment: La migración de vb6 a .net te va a obligar a reescribir mucho código. Debes asumir que será asi ,son dos tecnologías completamente diferentes :)